# How to limit the properties needed for the view from the model

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am working very hard to understand the concept of Entity Framework and Models by building a new MVC Architecture Solution.  I have started only with two Models that are identical to an (EXISTING DATABASE - That I must model after [Maybe comeback and re-factor later]), with a lot more models to come.

I get the data back to the VIEW no problem, however how do I scale down the CONTROLLER to only query items I need?  In this example I have the code committed out (see below), but if I cast .ToList() it throws an exception because that is not the Model Type.  I am sure I am missing something very simple, but I am stuck.  Any help would be great.

**VIEW**

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of CompanyName.Models.QAs)
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
Private ReadOnly _db As New Context

Function Faq() As ActionResult

        'Dim query As List(Of ShowFaqsModels)


        'query = From f In _db.Faqs _
        '         Where Not f.Hk_DeletedDt.HasValue _
        '         Or f.Hk_DeletedDt = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1) _
        '         And f.Active = 1 _
        '         Order By f.CategoryId Descending _
        '         Select f.Question, f.Answer


        Return View(_db.Faqs)
    End Function
```

**MODEL**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Namespace Models
    Public Class QAs
        <Key>
        Public Property QuestionId As Integer
        Public Property CategoryId As Integer
        Public Property Question As String
        Public Property Answer As String
        Public Property Active As Integer
        Public Property Hk_CreatedDt As DateTime
        Public Property Hk_ModifiedDt As DateTime
        Public Property Hk_DeletedDt As System.Nullable(Of DateTime)

    End Class
End Namespace
```

************ EDIT **********

**CONTROLLER**

```
  Function Faq() As ActionResult

        Dim faqs = From f In _db.Faqs _
                   Where Not f.Hk_DeletedDt.HasValue _
                   Or f.Hk_DeletedDt = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1) _
                   And f.Active = 1 _
                   Order By f.CategoryId Descending _
                   Select New FaqViewModel With {
                                                    .Question = f.Question,
                                                    .Answer = f.Answer
                                                }


        Return View(faqs)
    End Function
```

**Addition - Created a new Folder called "ViewModels" --- Did this to Only Use the Data need in the View.**

**VIEWMODELS**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Namespace ViewModels
    Public Class FaqViewModel
        Public Property Question As String
        Public Property Answer As String
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Thanks again to the contributors on this.  I am starting to figure out this puzzle and architect this solution.   Yes yes I know you can separate out in to other projects, but this site is not needed for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to return `"...(Select f.Question, f.Answer).ToList()"` which would not result in a model of type `CompanyName.Models.QAs`.
Therefore either return the whole `f.ToList()` OR
Use ViewModels if you think that the Model has so many extra properties that you wont need all of them in your view. ViewModels are also like models but they are for your views in contrast with Models which basically reflect your database tables/relations in essence. If your view needs only 2 fields out of maybe 50 fields in your model than make a ViewModel for that view.

Comment: LIGHT BULB!   zeppelin, let me know if I get this correct and please understand that I am trying to limit across the wire data as much as possible.  Making this site lean is the key because more data = more bandwidth = more cost, when you are talking 1,000,000+ sessions a month.   As soon as I changed the code to "...(Select f.Question, f.Answer).ToList()" it worked.  Now I am going to attempt creating a ViewModel to stream line.  thank you so much.  Nick, thank you as well.  Great help today.  It is great to get help and not get bashed.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your model as you're describing it is your data model. The best practice for passing or accepting information to/from your view(s) is to use a new class as a view model. It will have only the information necessary for the view and nothing else.

The catch is that these are not always a 1 to 1 mapping (though some of might be). For example, my view models routinely have other information on them, such as collections required for dropdowns, boolean flags indicating if certain areas of the page should be rendered, api keys needed to passing along to javascript resources. It all depends on what your view's needs, but the ideas is that you give the view everything it requires, it should not have to go out and get  it itself, unless there's no other way (which does happen in my experience).

Translating between data model and view model is something people have created specific tools for (like AutoMapper), just be aware that most rely on naming conventions of your object's properties being the same, and most would argue it's a bad practice to use an automapper-like solution for accepting information back from the browser.